# How to write an easy for loop for my function in RStudio? (R script below)

Tags: rstudio

I received an R script from my prof., it can convert an input adjacency matrix to a network format output. It works properly.

I'd like to write a for loop to make the file converting faster. My input files are in .csv format:  ["a (1).csv", ..., "a (128).csv"]. This is my code:

```
for(x in 2:128)
+ {
+ convert("a (x).csv", "000x.net")
+ }
```

And here's the error message:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'a (x).csv': No such file or directory
```

Could you tell me what's wrong with my code? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put the x in your character strings -- R doesn't know that you want to use the value of x that you're looping through.  You can do it like this:

`paste('a (', x, ').csv', sep='')`

This pastes the *value* of x in the for loop into a new character string each time you loop through, which should match your file names.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I've modified my codes, but it still displays an error message. =(

`for(x in 2:128)
{
  convert(paste('a (', x, ').csv', sep=''), paste('a (', x, ').net', sep='')
}`






`Error: unexpected '}' in:
"convert(paste('a (', x, ').csv', sep=''), paste('a (', x, ').net', sep='')
}"`





What could disturb R now?

Comment: I think you're just missing the closing parenthesis on your second paste statement.  Try this:`for(x in 2:128) { 
  convert(paste('a (', x, ').csv', sep=''), paste('a (', x, ').net'), sep='') 
}
`

Comment: `Error in convert(paste("a (", x, ").csv", sep = ""), paste("a (", x, ").net"),  : 
  unused argument (sep = "")`

Comment: Sorry, move that parenthesis to after the sep='' argument: `for(x in 2:128) { 
  convert(paste('a (', x, ').csv', sep=''), paste('a (', x, ').net', sep='')) 
}
`